# List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type 'string' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to post my data which consist an array of cartItems and other information. But could not get through it.

The api from laravel is generated as follows like in image[image]

My Request with postman

[image]

I am getting below error in the logcat:

```
   type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

E/flutter (13443): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'statusCode' was called on null.
E/flutter (13443): Receiver: null
E/flutter (13443): Tried calling: statusCode
E/flutter (13443): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter (13443): #1      new ResponseApi (package:kitabyatra/response/ResponseApi.dart:11:21)
E/flutter (13443): #2      ContentRepositoryImpl.dopostApiCallWithToken (package:kitabyatra/repository/ContentRepositoryImpl.dart:184:41)
E/flutter (13443): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13443): #3      ContentRepositoryImpl.doAddOrderApiCall (package:kitabyatra/repository/ContentRepositoryImpl.dart:515:18)
E/flutter (13443): #4      CheckoutPresenter.doAddOrderApiCall (package:kitabyatra/view/checkout/CheckoutPresenter.dart:552:81)
E/flutter (13443): #5      CheckoutState._buildDeliveryLocation.<anonymous closure> (package:kitabyatra/view/checkout/CheckoutView.dart:303:35)
E/flutter (13443): #6      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:993:19)
E/flutter (13443): #7      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1111:38)
E/flutter (13443): #8      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:183:24)
E/flutter (13443): #9      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:598:11)
E/flutter (13443): #10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:287:5)
E/flutter (13443): #11     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:259:7)
E/flutter (13443): #12     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
E/flutter (13443): #13     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:362:20)
E/flutter (13443): #14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:22)
E/flutter (13443): #15     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:267:11)
E/flutter (13443): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
E/flutter (13443): #17     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:240:7)
E/flutter (13443): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:213:7)
E/flutter (13443): #19     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (13443): #20     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (13443): #21     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (13443): #22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:265:10)
E/flutter (13443): #23     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:174:5)
```

My Response Api class

```
    class ResponseApi {

  int code;
  String body;
  String errorMessage;

  ResponseApi(Response response)
  {
    code = response.statusCode;

    if (isSuccessful())
    {
      body = response.body;
      errorMessage = '';
    }
    else
    {
      body = response.body;
      errorMessage = "";
    }
  }

  bool isSuccessful()
  {
    return code >= 100 && code < 600;
  }
}
```

I have implemented the postcall method as follows:

```
 @override
  Future<ResponseFormat<ResponseAddOrder>> doAddOrderApiCall(
      Map<String, dynamic> map) async {
    final String url = liveUrl + "user/order/product";
    print("Add Order ");
    print(url);
    return await dopostApiCallWithToken<ResponseAddOrder, ResponseAddOrder>(
        ResponseAddOrder(), url, map);
  }
```

I have handled my post method as follows:

```
@override
  Future<ResponseFormat<R>> dopostApiCallWithToken<T extends ResponseUni, R>(
      T obj, String url, Map map) async {
    Map valueMap = json.decode(JsonEncoder().convert(map));
    SecureStorageRepositoryImpl secureStorageRepositoryImpl =
        SecureStorageRepositoryImpl();
    String apiToken = await secureStorageRepositoryImpl.getApiToken();

    if (apiToken == null) {
      apiToken = "";
    }

    final Client client = http.Client();
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {'authorization': apiToken};
    try {
      final response = await http
          .post(
        '$url',
        headers: requestHeaders,
        body: valueMap,
      )
          .catchError((dynamic e) {
      
        print("${e.toString()}");
      });

print(response); ------>>> // Here I am getting null 

      final ResponseApi psApiResponse = ResponseApi(response);
      print(psApiResponse.errorMessage);
      print(psApiResponse.code);
      if (psApiResponse.isSuccessful()) {
        final dynamic hashMap = json.decode(response.body);

        if (!(hashMap is Map)) {
          final List<T> tList = <T>[];
          hashMap.forEach((dynamic data) {
            tList.add(obj.fromMap(data));
          });
          return ResponseFormat<R>(Status.SUCCESS, '', tList ?? R);
        } else {
          return ResponseFormat<R>(Status.SUCCESS, '', obj.fromMap(hashMap));
        }
      } else {
        return ResponseFormat<R>(
            Status.ERROR, psApiResponse.errorMessage, null);
      }
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  }
```

I have created my Request class as follows:

```
class RequestCheckOut extends RequestUni<RequestCheckOut> {
  RequestCheckOut({

    this.cartList,
    this.paymentId,
    this.price,
    this.deliveryAddressId,
    this.billingAddressId,
    this.discount,
    this.deliveryCharge,
    this.finalPrice,

  });
  var cartList;
  String paymentId;
  String price;
  String deliveryAddressId;
  String billingAddressId;
  String discount;
  String deliveryCharge;
  String finalPrice;



  @override
  RequestCheckOut fromMap(dynamic dynamicData) {
    if (dynamicData != null) {
      return RequestCheckOut(
        cartList : dynamicData['cartList'],
        paymentId : dynamicData['payment_id'],
        price : dynamicData['price'],
        deliveryAddressId : dynamicData['delivery_address_id'],
        billingAddressId : dynamicData['billing_address_id'],
        discount : dynamicData['discount'],
        deliveryCharge : dynamicData['delivery_charge_amt'],
        finalPrice : dynamicData['final_price'],


      );
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap()
  {
    var data = Map<String, dynamic>();

    data['cartList']=cartList;
    data['payment_id']=paymentId;
    data['price']=price;
    data['delivery_address_id']=deliveryAddressId;
    data['billing_address_id']=billingAddressId;
    data['discount']=discount;
    data['delivery_charge_amt']=deliveryCharge;
    data['final_price']=finalPrice;


    return data;
  }

  RequestCheckOut.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    cartList = (json['cartList']);
    paymentId = (json['payment_id']);
    price = (json['price']);
    deliveryAddressId = (json['delivery_address_id']);
    billingAddressId = (json['billing_address_id']);
    discount = (json['discount']);
    deliveryCharge = (json['delivery_charge_amt']);
    finalPrice = (json['final_price']);

  }
}
```

I have called the presenter from the view as follows:

```
  RequestCheckOut requestCheckout = RequestCheckOut(
                          cartList:widget.cartList,
                          paymentId: presenter.responsePayment.value.data
                              .paymentMethod[_value].id
                              .toString(),
                          price: widget.totalPrice.toString(),
                          deliveryAddressId: presenter.responseAddress.value
                              .data.addressList[toggleIndex].id
                              .toString(),
                          billingAddressId: presenter.responseAddress.value.data
                              .addressList[toggleIndex].id
                              .toString(),
                          discount: "0",
                          deliveryCharge: widget.shipPrice.toString(),
                          finalPrice: widget.totalPrice.toString(),
                        );
                     
                        presenter.doAddOrderApiCall(requestCheckout);
```

I have implemented doAddOrderApiCall in presenter as follows:

```
  doAddOrderApiCall(RequestCheckOut requestCheckOut) async
  {

    print("Do Add Order");
    view.showProgress();
    if (isConnectedToInternet)
    {
      print(requestCheckOut);
      final ResponseFormat<ResponseAddOrder> responseFormat = await contentRepo.doAddOrderApiCall(requestCheckOut.toMap());

      if(responseFormat.value.status)
      {

        view.hideProgress();
        view.showMessage(responseFormat.value.message);

        view.onBackPressed();

      }
      else
      {
        view.showMessage(responseFormat.value.message);
        view.hideProgress();
      }
    }
    else
    {

      view.hideProgress();
    }
  }
```

Response CartList

```
class ResponseCartList  extends ResponseUni<ResponseCartList>{
  bool status;
  String message;
  Data data;

  ResponseCartList({this.status, this.message, this.data});

  ResponseCartList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    message = json['message'];
    data = json['data'] != null ? new Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['message'] = this.message;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }

  @override
  fromMap(dynamicData) {
    if (dynamicData != null)
    {
      return ResponseCartList(
        status: dynamicData['status'],
        message: dynamicData['message'],
        data:dynamicData['data']!=null?Data.fromJson(dynamicData['data']):null,
      );
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  String getPrimaryKey() {
   return '';
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(object) {
    {
      if (object != null)
      {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
        data['status'] = object.status;
        data['message'] = object.message;
        data['data'] = object.data!=null?object.data.toJson():null;
        return data;
      }
      else
      {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
}

class Data {
  List<CartList> cartList;

  Data({this.cartList});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['cart_list'] != null) {
      cartList = new List<CartList>();
      json['cart_list'].forEach((v) {
        cartList.add(new CartList.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.cartList != null) {
      data['cart_list'] = this.cartList.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class CartList {
  int id;
  int productQty;
  int productId;
  String productSlug;
  String productName;
  String mrpPaperBook;
  String listingPrice;
  String productImage;

  CartList(
      {this.id,
        this.productQty,
        this.productId,
        this.productSlug,
        this.productName,
        this.mrpPaperBook,
        this.listingPrice,
        this.productImage});

  CartList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    productQty = json['product_qty'];
    productId = json['product_id'];
    productSlug = json['product_slug'];
    productName = json['product_name'];
    mrpPaperBook = json['mrp_paper_book'];
    listingPrice = json['listing_price'];
    productImage = json['product_image'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['product_qty'] = this.productQty;
    data['product_id'] = this.productId;
    data['product_slug'] = this.productSlug;
    data['product_name'] = this.productName;
    data['mrp_paper_book'] = this.mrpPaperBook;
    data['listing_price'] = this.listingPrice;
    data['product_image'] = this.productImage;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using var cartList try using it's type List<String> to avoid unnecessary dynamic

Comment: cartList consist of data from response

Comment: what kind of data? a list? is that list of type String?

Comment: List of Cartlist

Comment: I think I'm not explaining myself, var cartList is type of what kind exactly? 'CartList' is not a class as far as you showed in your code, is the variable cartList trying to save a List of strings? if thats the case instead of using var change it to List<String> cartList and in fromMap cartList : dynamicData['cartList'].?cast<String>()

Comment: I have edited my question with the CartListResponse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post method call

```
    @override
  Future<ResponseFormat<ResponseAddOrder>> doAddOrderApiCall(
      RequestCheckOut requestCheckOut) async {
    final String url = liveUrl + "user/order/product";
    print("Add Order ");
    print(url);
    return await dopostOApiCallWithToken<ResponseAddOrder, ResponseAddOrder>(
        ResponseAddOrder(), url, requestCheckOut);
  }
```

Changed post method as follows:

```
    @override
  Future<ResponseFormat<R>> dopostApiCallWithToken<T extends ResponseUni, R>(
    T obj,
    String url,
    var map,
  ) async {
    print(map);
    Map valueMap = json.decode(JsonEncoder().convert(map));
    var value = json.encode(map);

    print("Map value");

    print(value);

    SecureStorageRepositoryImpl secureStorageRepositoryImpl =
        SecureStorageRepositoryImpl();
    String apiToken = await secureStorageRepositoryImpl.getApiToken();

    if (apiToken == null) {
      apiToken = "";
    }

    final Client client = http.Client();

    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": apiToken

    };
    try {
      final response = await http
          .post(
        '$url',
        headers: requestHeaders,
        body: value,
      )
          .catchError((dynamic e) {
        print("Error");
        print("${e.toString()}");
      });
      print("Response");
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(json.decode(response.body));

      final ResponseApi psApiResponse = ResponseApi(response);
      print(psApiResponse.errorMessage);
      print(psApiResponse.code);
      if (psApiResponse.isSuccessful()) {
        final dynamic hashMap = json.decode(response.body);
        if (!(hashMap is Map)) {
          print("hash");
          print(hashMap);
          final List<T> tList = <T>[];
          hashMap.forEach((dynamic data) {
            tList.add(obj.fromMap(data));
            print("tList");
            print(tList);
          });
          return ResponseFormat<R>(Status.SUCCESS, '', tList ?? R);
        } else {
          return ResponseFormat<R>(Status.SUCCESS, '', obj.fromMap(hashMap));
        }
      } else {
        print("Error");
        return ResponseFormat<R>(
            Status.ERROR, psApiResponse.errorMessage, null);
      }
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  final response = await http
      .post(
    '$url',
    headers: requestHeaders,
    body: valueMap,
  ).catchError((dynamic e) { /// <-- somehting wrong happened here and is catched
  
    print("${e.toString()}");
  });
```

when sending the http request there is some error with the parsing, so its catched with the `catchError` and you print the error which is:

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

Because of that the response it's null, that's why printing result returns null, and after that when calling `final ResponseApi psApiResponse = ResponseApi(response);` the first line:

```
code = response.statusCode;
```

throws the rest of your error, because response is null and cannot call statusCode from a null object

```
E/flutter (13443): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'statusCode' was called on null.
E/flutter (13443): Receiver: null
E/flutter (13443): Tried calling: statusCode
.....
```

I'm still confident that your error (which is some kind of parsing) is related with your cartList, you declared it as `var cartList` and the json.decode / encode tries to parse it as it understands it, if your cartList is a `List` but you declared it as var it will just assume its a List, you need to change it to the correct type so the decoder/encoder use the correct toJson/fromJson

```
class RequestCheckOut extends RequestUni<RequestCheckOut> {
  RequestCheckOut({

    this.cartList,
    this.paymentId,
    this.price,
    this.deliveryAddressId,
    this.billingAddressId,
    this.discount,
    this.deliveryCharge,
    this.finalPrice,

  });
  Data cartList;  // <---- Here use exactly the type of object you want to be encoded, Data, List<CartList> or ResponseCartList
  String paymentId;
  String price;
  String deliveryAddressId;
  String billingAddressId;
  String discount;
  String deliveryCharge;
  String finalPrice;



  @override
  RequestCheckOut fromMap(dynamic dynamicData) {
    if (dynamicData != null) {
      return RequestCheckOut(
        cartList : dynamicData['cartList'], // <--- Here try to use the correct fromJson/ fromMap instead of let the machine try it to guess it for you, because it will just decode it from the simplest objects, String, num, etc., if it's Data then use Data.fromJson(dynamicData['cartList'])
        paymentId : dynamicData['payment_id'],
        price : dynamicData['price'],
        deliveryAddressId : dynamicData['delivery_address_id'],
        billingAddressId : dynamicData['billing_address_id'],
        discount : dynamicData['discount'],
        deliveryCharge : dynamicData['delivery_charge_amt'],
        finalPrice : dynamicData['final_price'],


      );
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap()
  {
    var data = Map<String, dynamic>();

    data['cartList']=cartList;
    data['payment_id']=paymentId;
    data['price']=price;
    data['delivery_address_id']=deliveryAddressId;
    data['billing_address_id']=billingAddressId;
    data['discount']=discount;
    data['delivery_charge_amt']=deliveryCharge;
    data['final_price']=finalPrice;


    return data;
  }

  RequestCheckOut.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    cartList = (json['cartList']);
    paymentId = (json['payment_id']);
    price = (json['price']);
    deliveryAddressId = (json['delivery_address_id']);
    billingAddressId = (json['billing_address_id']);
    discount = (json['discount']);
    deliveryCharge = (json['delivery_charge_amt']);
    finalPrice = (json['final_price']);

  }
}
```

Comment: Still same problem

Comment: I have edited my question with the method to post data in postman

Comment: check the update and try to do some debugging when decoding to make sure the objects are really what you want, also avoid var and dynamic when possible